# RavenDB: Prevent Index from returning revisions

Tags: .net, ravendb

I have RavenDB Versioning enabled and I have documents that look like this:

```
{
    Id: "mydoc/5",
    Count: 3,
    ... other data ...
}
```

I have an index that will return all documents that have a Count < 10.

```
docs.MyDocs.Where(mydoc => mydoc.Count < 10).Select(mydoc => 
new { Query = mydoc.Select(x => x.Value) });
```

When this query runs, I get results like this:

```
mydoc/5/revisions/1
{
    Id: "mydoc/5/revisions/1",
    Count: 2,
    ... other data ...
}

mydoc/5/revisions/2
{
    Id: "mydoc/5/revisions/2",
    Count: 3,
    ... other data ...
}

mydoc/5
{
    Id: "mydoc/5",
    Count: 3,
    ... other data ...
}
```

How should I change my index so it stops indexing the revisions of the documents and only returns the current version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can manipulate the index query to filter out all but "current" version. See: http://www.mostlylucid.co.uk/archive/2010/07/12/handy-indexes-for-versioning-with-ravendb.aspx

Comment: I'll give this a shot.  I am purely using the C# AbstractIndexCreationTask generic in order to keep this heavily type safe.  Any idea on how to implement this using that method?

Comment: You should be able to use something like:
Map = Objs => from obj in Objs select new { RevisionStatus =  this.MetadataFor(obj).Value<String>("Raven-Document-Revision-Status") }